# how to check CPU usage at linux system startup?

Tags: linux, process, top

I am stuck on finding a way to test CPU usage for a linux system at startup, usuing top or htop is too late for me to see the real usage at startup; is there an efficient way to it ?

Comment: It seems quite improbable to me being able to capture whatever as long as init is not launched. (Would whatever value be meaningful anyway since most of the boot process relies on the sole CPU#0 and others being plugged one after the other. Many ways are available when init has succesfully reached at least the first runlevel, they will all depends on your init system (busybox, rc, systemd…)

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the optimal solution, but you could try doing a cronjob on reboot to log the CPU usage to a file every second?

The script would look something like this:

```bash
watch -n 1 bash -c $'top -n 1 | head -n 3 | tail -n 1 | awk \'{print $2 + $4}\' >> ~/cpu-usage.csv'
```

- [`watch`](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr/blob/main/pages/linux/watch.md) to run a command every 1 second.
- [`top`](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr/blob/main/pages/linux/top.md) to check your CPU usage.
- [`head`](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr/blob/main/pages/common/head.md) to get the top 3 lines. (Had issues with `grep` in `watch`.)
- [`tail`](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr/blob/main/pages/common/tail.md) to get the last 1 line. (Had issues with `grep` in `watch`.)
- [`awk`](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr/blob/main/pages/common/awk.md) to select the columns we need and add the user/sys CPU usage.

Altogether, this will check the CPU usage every second and append the result to a file at `~/cpu-usage.csv`. From there you can add a cronjob on [`@reboot`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Nonstandard_predefined_scheduling_definitions) to run this script at startup.

You can edit your cronjobs with:

```bash
crontab -e
```

Then add the following:

```
@reboot watch -n 1 bash -c $'top -n 1 | head -n 3 | tail -n 1 | awk \'{print $2 + $4}\' >> ~/cpu-usage.csv'
```

We can't use a timed cronjob to run periodically because cron only has minute precision, which isn't helpful since you could launch top/htop yourself within a minute. You can change the arguments in this command to suit your needs, though!